# How do I create an Android notificaton in another thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, push-notification, android-context

I want to create a notification for my android app. I have it working fine when I run it with the rest of my code inside a class, everything executes when I click a button and the notification works fine. However, because there is a lot of work to be done, the application is running slowly when I click the button. To help this, I have separated the notification part into a class of it's own and I am running it on a different thread. 
I do not have a lot of experience with threads, or notifications for that matter and I would appreciate some help with this problem. Should I be separating the notification part into a class of it's own?

HomeActivity class is where the thread gets called to start, using the start() method when the button is clicked:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import Model.Data;

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private com.atmlocator.hooper.kenneth.atmlocator.Notification n;

public void addListenerOnButton() {

        locationSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        options1Spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        options2Spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        Button locate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.locateBtn);

        locate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            String text = "Loading...";

            //call notification thread here
            n.start();

            //rest of code here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then the Notification class is:

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class Notification extends FragmentActivity implements Runnable {

    private Thread t;
    private String name;
    Context context;

    Notification(String name, Context c)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.context = c;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        // Intent is triggered if the notification is selected
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

        // Build notification
        android.app.Notification not = new android.app.Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText("New email").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.atm)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        not.flags |= android.app.Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, not);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        t = new Thread (this, name);
        t.start ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I be separating the notification part into a class of it's own?

There should not be any problem with this!

Also you should show your notification outside a thread.
You can use a handler instead to show notification instead of thread

like this :

```
   }
....
 // write this outside your code block
 Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    showNotification();
}
};
// call it like this instead of thread start
 mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

check this link for more info : https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: Always try to find solution through Android Api's that are provided in the SDK itself. Trust me there are lots of good things in it :)

Answer (score 0):

This will virtually always work:

```
public static void toast(final String text, final int length, final Context context) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(context, text, length).show();
        }
    });
}
```